# Explicit isomorphism of a crossed product algebra

Tags: differential-geometry, operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Suppose $G$ is a Lie group acting properly on a (non-compact) manifold $M$ with compact orbit space. Then there is an induced action of $G$ on $C_0(M)$, the continuous $\mathbb{C}$-valued functions on $M$ vanishing at infinity, and we can form the crossed product algebra $C_0(M)\rtimes G$.

I was told that there is an isomorphism

$$C_0(M)\rtimes G\cong C(M,\mathcal{K}(L^2(G)))^G,$$

where $\mathcal{K}(L^2(G))$ denotes the $C^*$-algebra of compact operators on the Hilbert space $L^2(G)$, and the superscript $G$ means $G$-invariant functions. At first I didn't care to ask what the actual map would be, since so often it is the case that the "obvious map" turns out to be the right one; but in this case I can't seem to figure out what the obvious map should be.

**Question:** What should the isomorphism be? Is there a reference where I can read more about this isomorphism?

Comment: I think that it follows from the non-commutative version of Takai-duality.
If $G$ was commutative, then $(A\rtimes G)\rtimes \hat{G}$ was isomorphic to $A\otimes K(L^2(G))$ and by the definition of the dual action, one can deduce  that the crossed product $A\rtimes G$ is exactly the fixed point algebra under the action of $\hat{\hat{G}}\cong G$ on $(A\rtimes G)\rtimes \hat{G}$, which is transfered, by the isomorphism to $\alpha\otimes ad(\rho)$ on $A\otimes K$, where $\rho$ is the right regualr representation.

Comment: Regarding the map, notice that the natural equivariant inclusion $\iota: A\to A\otimes C(G)$ induces a map on the crossed product: $\iota: A\rtimes G\to A\otimes K(L^2(G))$ . This follows since $C(G)\rtimes G\cong K(L^2(G))$ , where the action is given by left translation.

Comment: I see, thanks for your comments! This looks to be on the right track. However, if one takes $A=C_0(M)$, we get a map $\iota:C_0(M)\rtimes G\rightarrow C_0(M)\otimes\mathcal{K}(L^2(G))$. But $C(M,\mathcal{K}(L^2(G)))^G$ does not seem be a subset of $C_0(M)\otimes\mathcal{K}(L^2(G))$? In particular, if a function $f$ is $G$-invariant and not identically $0$, and $G$ is non-compact group, then $f$ not in $C_0(M)$...